# error: no match for operator=in C++

Tags: c++

Hi I'm getting this error when compiling with g++ 4.1.2

> "error: no match for operator= in"
>   ((PoolElementList*)this)->PoolElementList::i_currentElement = ((PoolElementList*)this)->PoolElementList::i_elementList.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end with _Tp = ModifyTerminationPointReqInfo*, _Alloc = std::allocator

Definition of PoolElements is as follows:

```
template <class Element, Element *intialElementPtr>
class PoolElementList
{
        GenericMemoryPool <Element, intialElementPtr> *i_elementPoolPtr;

        vector <Element *> i_elementList;
        vector <Element *> i_currentElement;
public:

  //Define a constructor that takes in a pointer of the pool.
        PoolElementList(GenericMemoryPool <Element, intialElementPtr> *elementPool):
        i_elementPoolPtr (elementPool)
        { 
                i_currentElement = i_elementList.end();   //error is here**
        };
```

Please someone can explain what could be wrong in this. (This was compiling in g++ 2.9.x)

Comment: What is `i_currentElement = i_elementList.end();` supposed to do? Did you mean to make `i_currentElement` a `std::vector<Element *>::iterator`? It also looks like your constructor body ends with a semicolon. Usually, function bodies don't.

Comment: The problem is that you can't assign an iterator to a vector...What is your goal here?

Comment: yes I wanted to have i_currentElement as std::vector<Element *>::iterator

Answer (score 0):

If (as you said in your comment) you intend for `i_currentElement` to be a  `std::vector<Element *>::iterator`, then you must declare it as one. Simply replace

```
vector <Element *> i_elementList;
```

with

```
vector <Element *>::iterator i_elementList;
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for ur quick reply

I changed the code as follows:

vector <Element *>::iterator i_currentElement;
and getting this errors.

error: type std::vector<Element*, std::allocator<Element*> > is not derived from type PoolElementList<Element, intialElementPtr>
error: expected ; before i_currentElement

Why they g++ is not backward compatible? (I'm a newbie) Actually we are porting to code to new platform, so we are building this old code. Need to understand the code in detailed (Pending action item)